# Showing SAP Fiori App Tile only for a time period

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, sap-gateway

Is there a way to show a Tile just for a Time Period?

e.g. Show Fiori App Tile just in December but not in other Months.

I'm looking for a way to code that. Is there maybe a OData Service where the catalog/group for the user is loaded? Maybe, could it be possible to manipulate the Tiles catalog dynamically there?

I'm open for any suggestions!

I'm currently looking for an OData Service which loads the Employees catalog und hoping there is like a table with the maintained tiles. Nothing found yet.

Comment: Hi Jfenris.
My approach would be to play with the validity periods of the roles which would give access to the catalog in which your tile would be.
Cause Fiori applications are role-based and we can manage the validity periods of the roles.
There are probably other approaches.

Comment: @depth1 Thanks for your answer. i am aware of that. The roles do have validity periods but not periodically. It is a fixed period. I wanted to maintain a periodically possibility e.g. every January.

Answer (score 0):

That also depends on which Fiori landscape are you refering to. Are you in Netweaver or SAP Build Work zone? In any case @depth1 is absolute right as both are role based. Howeve in netweaver the OData services which controls the content of the launchpad are PAGE_BUILDER_CONF, PAGE_BUILDER_CUST and PAGE_BUILDER_PERS (found in /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE)

You might create your own tile type and check enhancement spot /UI2/ES_FDM and BAdI /UI2/BADI_FDM_PUB_CUST_TILE or maybe spot /UI2/ES_PAGE and BAdI /UI2/BADI_PROCESS_CATALOG_IDS.